# C++ after initialize char[] and char , char shows in the char[]

Tags: c++, lldb

I'm learning Cpp recently, and today when I use Clion to learn do some testing strange thing happened.

Here is my code

```
int main() {
    char c = 'b';
    char carr[1]{'a'};
    char *p1 =&(carr[0]);
    char *p2 =&c;
    return 0;
}
```

Complier:

4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)

lldb :

[image: lldb]

And here is the details of memory:
[image]

Please help me to figure out the reasons!

Comment: Regarding the first image at least: please don't post plain text in images. Copy-paste it into the question instead. See [ask].

Comment: `some testing strange thing` Please elaborate more specific, what is strange?

Comment: LLDB expects `carr` to be null-terminated, and goes out of bounds when trying to find the null-terminator. It's a coincidence that `c` ended up right after `carr` in memory, and that there was a null byte right after `c`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why does lldb not recognize that the type is an array type rather than pointer and assume the length from that (in the `p carr` case)? gdb does print only the array contents.

Comment: @walnut Because it's being silly, I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the lldb data formatter for strings being a little too eager.

People looking at char arrays in the debugger don't generally want a char[N] to print as an array of N char's, they want to see it as a string.  So lldb provides a "data formatter" for char[*] that presents it as a C string.  The formatter really should hand-null terminate that string at the length of the array.  You can see the (overly simplistic) data formatter by doing:

```
(lldb) type summary info carr
summary applied to (char [1]) carr is: `${var%s}` (hide value) (skip pointers)
```

It just says start at the start of the array and print the memory as a C-string.

You can see the real array by turning off the data formatter for char types with the --raw option when you print the variable:

```
(lldb) v --raw carr
(char [1]) carr = {
  [0] = 'a'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `carr` is of type `char[1]` which decays to `char*`.
When trying to print a `char*` your debugger keeps printing chars until it reaches a null terminator `\0`.

It's not that `carr` contains `"ab"`, but rather that any function looking at `carr` would assume that it does. This is because the bounds of the array are (almost always) discarded when it is passed to another function.

Comment: But OP is not trying to print the array. They are asking the debugger for its contents and the debugger knows the exact type `char[1]`. Why does LLDB decide to print it as if it was a pointer, rather than printing the actual array contents which seems much more reasonably to me? GDB follows the later logic based on my testing.

Comment: I would guess that this is a bug in LLDB.